# Windows 10 does not reboot on BSOD

Tags: windows-10, bsod, reboot

I have often BSOD on my system, but additional problem is that system does not reboot after them.

After BSOD it normally indicates dump progress up to 100%, then stays in this position forever.

[image]

How to make it proceed to reboot automatically?

**UPDATE**

Of course, reboot option is set

[image]